# Finding all continuous functions so that $f^n(x)=x$ for some $n$.

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

I came up with this problem in class but I can't seem to solve it. I need to find all the functions $f$ with domain and codomain $\mathbb R$ such that there is an $n$ such that $f^n(x)=x$ for all $x$, where $f^n(x)=f(f(f\dots f(x))\dots)$

I'm not really sure what to do. I think when we ask for $n$ to be $2$ is is only $f(x)=x$ and $f(x)=-x$

Comment: Usually these kinds of things go the other way around.. but here is someone's post from earlier today on /r/math on this exact matter (usually an MSE post is linked on reddit): http://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/2tvjbf/proof_no_continuous_function_can_satisfy_ffffxx/. The timing is weird though.

Comment: I don't know what a reddit is, what do you mean the timing is weird?

Comment: Weird insofar that on the exact same day, two people brought up this exact (*very* specific) question.

Comment: well, I came up with the question myself. I don't know what to say, although initially I only considered continuous involutions.

Comment: I think the stuff in the link is wrong though.

Comment: I'm not accusing you! It's just that it's almost eerie, I guess. For instance, one day I had a thought about whether there had been any serious blind mathematicians and later that day, someone posted on here asking that exact question. Weird coincidences!

Comment: oh I see, sorry then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully I am not making a stupid mistake.

Since $f$ is continuous and 1-1, it must be strictly monotonic.

**Case 1:** $f$ is inceasing. We prove that $f(x)=x$.

Assume by contradiction that $f(x_0) \neq x_0$ for some $x_0$. Therefore $f(x_0) < x_0$ or $f(x_0) > x_0$.

By induction on $k$ you can then prove that $f^k(x_0) <x_0$ in the first case and $f^k(x_0) > x_0$. Therefore $f^n(x_0) \neq x_0$ contradiction.

**Case 2:** $f$ is decreasing.

As $f^n$ is increasing then $n$ must be **even.**  Let $n=2k$.

Then the function $g(x)=f \circ f(x)$ is increasing and satisfies $g^k(x)=x$. By Case 1, it follows that $g(x)=x$, and hence we reduced the problem to the case $n=2$.

So we know that $f$ is decreasing and $f \circ f(x) =x$.

It follows from the Intermediate Value Theorem that $f$ has an unique fixed point $a$. I think one can prove that this implies that
$$f(x)=a-x$$

**Added**
Actually that is not true.

Let $g$ be any continuous decreasing bijection from $(-\infty, a]$ to $[a, \infty)$.

Then 
$$f= g(x) \mbox{ if } x \leq a $$
$$f= g^{-1}(x) \mbox{ if } x > a $$

has the desired property, and it is easy to see that this describes all the solutions to the equation.

Comment: I think it should be: by induction on $k$ you can then prove that $f^k(x_0)>x_0$ not $f_k(x_0)>0$

Comment: @ModdedBear Thank you. The case $n=2$ still needs work, as $f(x)=a-x$ is a solution.

Comment: @ModdedBear Check my addon.

Comment: "By induction on $k$ you can then prove that $f^k(x_0)<x_0$ in the first case" how?

Comment: @ModdedBear Since $f$ is increasing $f^k(x_0) <x_0$ implies $f^{k+1}(x_0) < f(x_0)$ and you know that $f(x_0) < x_0$.

Answer (score 1):

There are many more solutions for $n=2$ such as

- $f(x) = k-x$
- $f(x)=-3\sqrt{x}$ when $x \ge 0$ and $f(x)=\dfrac{x^2}{9}$ when $x\lt 0$.

It is possible to build many more weird and wonderful complicated but still continuous functions like these.

Note that any solution for $n=2$ is also a solution for even $n$.